# Getting ECONNREFUSED calling an external API with NextJS application using Auth0

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, auth0

I have currently implemented Auth0 authentication on my NextJS app by following their docs, and am trying to call an external ExpressJS application by following their docs: https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/blob/main/EXAMPLES.md#access-an-external-api-from-an-api-route.

I have NextJS running on port `3000` and Express running on port `3001`.

My express server is set up as follows:

```
const jwtCheck = expressjwt({
    secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: process.env.AUTH0_JWKS_URI as string,
    }) as GetVerificationKey,

    audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE as string,
    issuer: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER as string,
    algorithms: ['RS256'],
})

app.use(jwtCheck)
```

When I try to make an unauthenticated request from my NextJS app to the external API, I get the `UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found error` which ensures it is working. If I comment out `app.use(jwtCheck)` the requests are successful as there is no auth check.

I have my NextJS application set up as follows:

```
// [...auth0].ts


import { handleAuth, handleLogin } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0'

export default handleAuth({
    login: handleLogin({
        authorizationParams: {
            audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE, // or AUTH0_AUDIENCE
            // Add the `offline_access` scope to also get a Refresh Token
            scope: 'openid profile email read:trips', // or AUTH0_SCOPE
        },
    }),
})


// /api/trips.ts


import { getAccessToken, withApiAuthRequired } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0'

const apiURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL

export default withApiAuthRequired(async function trips(req, res) {
    // If your access token is expired and you have a refresh token
    // `getAccessToken` will fetch you a new one using the `refresh_token` grant
    const { accessToken } = await getAccessToken(req, res, {
        scopes: ['read:trips'],
    })

    const response = await fetch(`${apiURL}/trips`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            Accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
    })

    const trips = await response.json()
    res.status(200).json(trips)
})

// /pages/trips/index.tsx

const TripsPage = (props: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>) => {
    if (!props.user) return <div>User error!</div>


    return (
        <div>
            // components that use the fetched data
        </div>
    )
}


export const getServerSideProps = withPageAuthRequired({
    async getServerSideProps() {

        const { data } = await axios.get('/api/trips')

        try {
            return {
                props: {
                    data: data,
                },
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return {
                notFound: true,
            }
        }
    },
})

export default TripsPage
```

However, when I try to go to the `http://localhost:3000/trips` page after logging in, I get a error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/trips 500 (Internal Server Error)
Uncaught Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:80
    at <unknown> (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:80)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16)
```

It seems like the request doesn't even leave my NextJS application. Seems like the internal API call failed. However, if I directly go to `http://localhost:3000/api/trips` I **do get a response** with the JSON data and if I console.log the accessToken it is valid. So authentication is working, but the issue is in the actual page which calls the NextJS proxy API, which calls my ExpressJS API.

The full error log on the NextJS console is:

[image]

```
error - AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16) {
  port: 80,
  address: '::1',
  syscall: 'connect',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: -4078,
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.27.2'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: '/api/trips',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError],
      socket: [Function: handleRequestSocket]
    },
    _eventsCount: 3,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      protocol: 'http:',
      path: '/api/trips',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: null,
      port: null,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/api/trips'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: true,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET /api/trips HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.27.2\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/api/trips',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    _currentUrl: 'http:/api/trips',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  page: '/trips'
}
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. I had the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was that we not allowed to call an internal NextJS `/api/` route in `getServerSideProps`. We need to call the external API directly, and not through the internal `/api` proxy.

More information: https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/issues/995